# Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | string[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular-12, I have this in the token service:

```
get(){
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}
```

Then I tried to utilize it from another service as follows for CORS:

```
httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": 'application/json',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept",
    "Authorization" : this.token.get()
  })
};

//GET Method
public getAll(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.api.baseURL + 'list', this.httpOptions);
}
```

I got this error:

> Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | string[]'

and:

> "Authorization"

is highlighted.

Even when I changed httpOptions to:

```
httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Authorization' : this.token.get(),
  'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'
  })
};
```

Same error occurs.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Note that `Access-Control-*` headers are *Response* headers and must be received by the browser from the server. Sending them from the browser to the receiver as Request headers makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with that

if localStorage.getItem('token') return null, this code return []
So get() function return string | []

```
get(){
  return localStorage.getItem('token') ?? [];
}
```

or
if localStorage.getItem('token') return null, this code return ""
So get() function return string | string

```
get(){
  return localStorage.getItem('token') ?? "";
}
```

or

This solution isn't good but sometime remove compilation error

```
get(): any{
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}
```

Comment: Please explain what it does and why it solves OP issue.

Comment: Also last option should not be the solution. Typing things as `any` defeat the purpose of Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear: `this.token.get()` returns `string | null` whereas `HttpHeaders` expects values of type `string | string[]`.

You need to handle the possibility that there is no token in the local storage: the `null` value returned by `get()`.

Depending on how you want to handle it, you can either do it in your `get()` method or when building `httpOptions`.

Comment: So... is this a duplicate of the question you posted or not?

Comment: @Gaël J - In the local storage the token is there. it appears this way:        token Bearer dsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsds

Comment: It is but it could be absent as well. That's what the types are telling. If you are sure to always have a value, you can ignore the null but always better to handle it.